# How to install java 32bit version

Tags: java, 32-bit, jre

I need a java jre 32bit version, how can I install it in my Ubuntu Server 18.10? I could only install the 64bit version of jvm.

Comment: By the way I think Ubuntu dropped 32 bits version from 18.04 so do you really need 32 bit Java on Ubuntu 18.10?

Comment: Unfurtunately, I have some 32bit native libraries that I cannot compile for 64bit...

Answer (score 1):

Download of Java 32-Bit-Version for Linux: https://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp

Answer (score 0):

After java 8 there is no more 32 bit Oracle virtual machine. I think the same is for OpenJDK. You can search if you want for another virtual machine which has 32 bit and after that install it.

For example I see that Azul has 32 bit machine. But honestly I never test them. Maybe there are other JVM providers with 32 bit machines: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-linux/

By the way I also don't know what kind of licences they have.

Apart from that Ubuntu 18.10 by default try to install OpenJDK 11. If you are OK with java 8 you can search how to install java 8 32 bits.

Good luck!